# Cisco Certificate CA Server and SCEP - adding RADIUS authentication

Tags: cisco, radius

I am running a CA server on a Cisco ASR1k Router for several years. until now the number of SCEP clients is quite small (below 10) that it is possible to restrict SCEP Downloads by implementing a ACL.

The number of SCEP Clients will  soon increase to about 1000, a lot with changing IP addressing, so using ACLs is not practical any more.

So i decided to utilize RADIUS authentication to the CA to bring a more scaleable Access-Control to it.

Here is my running configuration:

```
crypto pki server NETPKI
 database archive pkcs12 password XXX
 issuer-name cn=XXX,o=XXX
 grant auto
 hash sha256
 lifetime ca-certificate 7305
 auto-rollover
!
crypto pki trustpoint NETPKI
 revocation-check crl
 rsakeypair RSA-KEY
```

I'm already using a productive RADIUS Configuration on the Server to authenticate BNG subscribers.
The Existing RADIUS Configuration is:

```
aaa group server radius GRP-RADIUS
 server name RAD1
 server name RAD2
 server name RAD3
!
aaa authorization network NETRAD group GRP-RADIUS
```

according to the documentation i found it should be nough to add following lines to the "crypto pki trustpoint NETPKI" Config-Block:

```
authorization list NETRAD
authorization username subjectname serialnumber
```

But this didn't work. I enabled RADIUS Debugging and requested a new Cerificate via SCEP. I received a valid Certificate, but couldn't notice any RADIUS communication in the debugs.

Any hints if i'm missing a Configuration statement or anything?

**Edit1:**
Cisco's Documentation [Configuring Authorization and Revocation of Certificates in a PKI](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9300/software/release/17-9/configuration_guide/sec/b_179_sec_9300_cg/configuring_authorization_and_revocation_of_certificates_in_a_pki.html) is confusing. It says that these lines should be added in global (config)# mode. But this is not possible. The ca-trustpoint is the only Config block where this lines are applicable.

Comment: Shouldn't the AAA apply to the http server, since that's the gateway to the CA? The user/pass under the trustpoint would only be for any req's.

Comment: i think the aim is authorizing the signing of the cert-request on the CA Server, independent of how the cert is enrolled. 
Cisco's Documentation (https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9300/software/release/17-9/configuration_guide/sec/b_179_sec_9300_cg/configuring_authorization_and_revocation_of_certificates_in_a_pki.html) is confusing. 
It says that this lines should be added in global (config) mode. But this is not possible. The ca-trustpoint is the only Config block where this lines are applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working, primary with the help of this Document: [Zero-Touch-Deployment-ZTD-of-VPN-Remote](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-architecture-implementation/200031-Zero-Touch-Deployment-ZTD-of-VPN-Remot.pdf)
Halleluja!